# Can I pursue a PhD program that is different from my MA?

Tags: phd, masters, teaching, translations

I have a Master's Degree in Translation, and I am wondering if it's possible to pursue a PhD in TESOL (Teaching English as a Second Language). They're in the same field, but different programs.

Comment: What country or countries?

Comment: I don't see why you can't do that PhD!

Answer (score 1):

If you feel qualified and the research is compelling to you is the best indicator of if a programme suits you. As described, it seems you are most likely qualified, so applying should not be a concern (given the limited information provided about your specific situation). Understanding the faculty you'd be working with, and the projects available to you is also a good indication if the program is suited both to your interests and skillset.